# How to Convert List<'a> to other object list?

Tags: c#, linq, api

i want result linq statement convert to other list in Web Api

```
 var data = Base_Tables.db.Lines.Find(id).Owner_Line.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID)
                                .Select(x => new { x.ID, Caption = x.Name1 + " " + x.Name2 + " " + x.Name3 })
                                .ToList();

List<HistoryLine> historyList = data as List<HistoryLine>();
```

**Class HistoryLine**

```
public class HistoryLine
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Caption { get; set; }
    }
```

> How to Convert ? , if can't convert statement, any way to fix this problem ?

Comment: Change the type of data from 'var data' to 'List<HistoryLine> data'. Then the intellisense will tell you exactly what is wrong with your code 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply select into the object you want instead of an anonymous type.

```
var data = Base_Tables.db.Lines
    .Find(id).Owner_Line
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.ID)
    .Select(x => new HistoryLine {ID = x.ID, Caption = x.Name1 + " " + x.Name2 + " " + x.Name3})
    .ToList();
```

data is now a `List<HistoryLine>`

Comment: No data is List<‘a> now, because using select ,

Comment: @ZanyarJ.Ahmed, read my edit again, it's a `List<HistoryLine>` because you selected INTO `HistoryLine`, without specifying it, you are creating an anonymous object.

Comment: .Select(x => new { x.ID, Caption = x.Name1 + " " + x.Name2 + " " + x.Name3 }) is the issue. use .Select(x => new HistoryLine { x.ID, Caption = x.Name1 + " " + x.Name2 + " " + x.Name3 })

Comment: new HistoryLine

Comment: @gilliduck i haven’t computer now , later try your code , are you sure work ?

Comment: @ZA: I can vouch for his code. It will give you List<HistoryLine> in data. My prev comment explains the difference of why yours fails. You are using an anonymous type. he is not.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types